# Is DateFormatter class broken in swift 3?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I am trying to use Date class which is provided from Swift 3 library. I am not sure if I am doing it right.
When I print Date it prints correct date, but when I try to convert it from date to string it changes the date to something else.

```
let today = Date()
print(" Date object : \(today)")

let format = DateFormatter()
format.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy"

print(" Date to String : \(format.string(from: today)")
```

Which gives the output:

> Date object : 2017-06-03 18:13:39 +0000
>
> Date to String : 13/03/17

Comment: `mm` is minutes, you want `MM` for months.

Comment: "Is `DateFormatter` class broken in Swift 3?" - [No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44347326/1271826).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mm` is the format specifier for minutes, hence why the output returns `13` instead of `06`, which is the time in minutes at which you called `Date()`.

You'll need to use `MM` to display the month.

See the unicode report on date specifiers for more information: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: (FYI, my VPN reports that web site as one that has been "reported as harmful". I might direct people to Apple's site, https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter, or the site that they direct you to for date format strings, http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 1):

No it doesnt.
Your format is Minute, Day and Year.
Works exactly as it should.

Try MM istead of mm.